# How can i write GPS data to file with a button or periodically?

Tags: android

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
try {
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("DataWriteTry.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
    outputStream.write(data);
    outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
```

I tried this code, to do the data writing with a button but it didn't worked.

```
writeToFile(getText(loc.getAltitude()));
```

I tried the "writeToFile" with getText, String and with the defined textView.
How can i write this data with a button or automatically every 15. minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i do it

```
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myfile.txt", false);
            BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            br.append(data);
            br.close();
            fw.close();
```

The file is saved in your external storage root directory

Try changing this line

```
writeToFile(getText(loc.getAltitude()));
```

To

```
writeToFile(String.valueOf(loc.getAltitude()));
```

Ok you can solve that by setting a class variable

```
Location location = null;
```

Then in your onLocationChanged callback set the class variable location like this

```
this.location = loc;
```

then you can call

```
writeToFile(String.valueOf(location.getAltitude()));
```

from your onClick callback

Comment: Thank you it is helpful but my main problem is how can i make the code to reach the GPS Altitude data for example. I dont know how to make it to write the data what i wanted.

Comment: For that you have to show how you are getting the location information, one line is not sufficient to figure that out, If you can post the code where you get location data, i can look at it and possibly provide you solution

Comment: public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        double Alt = loc.getAltitude();
        textViewAlt.setText("Altitude :" + Alt);
This is How i get and write the data to a textView.

Comment: can you post this in your question in code block so thats its more readable and everyone can see right away. Also is your textview showing the data?

Comment: I reading about how to put it in a code block. And yes, it showing the data.
    `public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {`
    `double Alt = loc.getAltitude();`
    'textViewAlt.setText("Altitude :" + Alt);'

Comment: The second one working if i put it under the "onLocationChanged". This is where i get the data. If i put it under the "onClick" it says: loc cannot be resolved.

Comment: When i get the GPS data and i push the button the app is crashing with java.lang.NullPointerException. Maybe the `Location location = null;` is the problem because it cant be null?

Comment: I set to null without problem. I wrote this tutorial while back. Check this out:http://androidtutorials-codes.blogspot.com/2013/03/android-app-development-201-1st.html

Comment: I still have the crash if i try to get the data from an editText. I will try your external storage code.

Comment: @Peshal since you know the type of getAltitude(), you should use Double.ToString instead of String.valueOf

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a [Android Alarms](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) or a [`TimerTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) with an accompanying [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. in order to get the location, you have to wait till you get one from the location sensors , so it can't be using a push of a button. the only similar thing to this would be to get the last location that is known, but that could either be very far from the real location or just return null.
2. in order to write to a file every 15 minutes, there are plenty of ways. the simplest is using an AlarmManager to schedule an event, and append the location to the file.

   another possible way is to have a foreground service that keeps your app alive, and requests from the location sensors to be notified of a new location every 15 minutes.
3. google has released a nice API to be used with their play services (link [here](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/324498944)), which has many advantages over using the normal location sensors (battery, speed , accuracy,...) .

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your question, it looks like you have no knowledge about Android and you are trying to make an app requiring intermediate level knowledge. Anyhow, you can write to the file in `onLocationChanged`, this method will be called after the time and distance you have specified in `requestLocationUpdates()`.